# How can I convert String to JsonObject?

Tags: android, json, string

```
{
   "error":null,
   "countries":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "description":"Slovensko",
         "locale":"sk_SK",
         "zipRegexp":"/^\\d{3}\\ ?\\d{2}$/"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "description":"Česká republika",
         "locale":"cs_CZ",
         "zipRegexp":null
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "description":"Afganistan",
         "locale":"en_EN",
         "zipRegexp":null
      }
    ]
}
```

and so on so on, now I need to convert it to JsonObject on Android. **But I cannot convert it to String because of *double commas***. How can it be done? I need somethink like this:

```
JsonObjet.JsonFromString('{"error":null,"countries":[{"id":1,"description":"Slovensko","locale":"sk_SK","zipRegexp":"/^\\d{3}\\ ?\\d{2}$/"},{"id":2,"description":"Česká republika","locale":"cs_CZ","zipRegexp":null}}');
```

this is not the answer:

```
JSONObject getJSON = new JSONObject("{"error":null,"countries":[{"id":1,"description":"Slovensko","locale‌​":"sk_SK","zipRegexp":"/^\\d{3}\\ ?\\d{2}$/"},{"id":2,"description":"Česká republika","locale":"cs_CZ","zipRegexp":null}}");
```

because of double commas.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject getJSON = new JSONObject("Your String");
```

### Edit:

```
String yourString = "{"+"\"error\""+":"+"\"no error\""+"}";
System.out.println(yourString );
```

Then `yourString` will be `{"error":"no error"}`. Implement the same way for the String you have. Then convert the above `yourString` to JSONObject as

```
JSONObject getJSON = new JSONObject(yourString);
```

Comment: but how can I achieve the "res" because I can not convert the it to String because of double commas in my original Json. because It does not work: JSONObject getJSON = new JSONObject("{"error":null,"countries":[{"id":1,"description":"Slovensko","locale":"sk_SK","zipRegexp":"/^\\d{3}\\ ?\\d{2}$/"},{"id":2,"description":"Česká republika","locale":"cs_CZ","zipRegexp":null}}");

Comment: Your JSONObject ios wrong.you missed close bracket [ of countries in your json result.

Comment: I just copied some entries, the original Json is ok and valid I have tested it with http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: But how can I parse to String that Json. There are lot of double commas so It cannot be like String myString = "{"error":"no error"}";

Comment: If you have `"` then you have to parse it correctly. For example, if you have `{"error":"no error"}`, then it should be `String str= "{"+"error"+":"+"no error"+"}";` and do for all the `"`

Comment: Now check. This should work. `String str= "{"+""+"error"+""+":"+""+" no error"+""+"}";`

Comment: I have not, the workaround is with adding before double commas backslas like this \" it is a way, now i am implementing it. Hope it will work well. But THANKS all of you for your answers

Comment: What have you added do not leav there the double commas, but if you edit your answer with the backslash version i will accept, it!

Comment: Okay. I will add with backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

How do you get the JSon??? If you are getting it from a HttpClient then get it as a InputStream and use the bufferedReader to convert it into a String buffer.

Comment: I have it. I get it in mail from my colegaue, app has no acces to net, and I want to display him a list of countries

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
```

Comment: but how can I achieve the "res" because I can not convert the it to String because of double commas in my original Json

Comment: You can add back slash before double coute like this

Comment: String res = "{\"error\":null,\"countries\":[{\"id\":1,\"description\":\"Slovensko\",\"locale\":\"sk_SK\",\"zipRegexp\":\"/^\\d{3}\\ ?\\d{2}$/\"},{\"id\":2,\"description\":\"Česká republika\",\"locale\":\"cs_CZ\",\"zipRegexp\":null},{\"id\":3,\"description\":\"Afganistan\",\"locale\":\"en_EN\",\"zipRegexp\":null}}";

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
        InputStream mIs = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jObjectLogin = null;

           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           String urlWithNoSpace=  url.replace(" ", "%20");
           HttpGet httpget = new   HttpGet(urlWithNoSpace);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            mIs = entity.getContent();

            String result = "";
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mIs,"UTF-8"),8);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

             //if require change or edit this condition.     
             if(line.trim().equals("\n"))
                    continue;
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            mIs.close();
            result=stringBuilder.toString();
```

Now as according to string format(which is in Json format) you can fetch array and objects from it.

```
     JSONObject jsonObject=result ;
     JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("countries");
```

now put loop and find values fron Array.

Comment: but I already have the Json, and I do not have a webservice to get one. I just got it and have to implement it to application. I do not have acces to internet. So I need to convert it somehow to String then to Json Object than to Json array, and I can acces the data. But I do not know how to do that

Comment: then put you Json directly in String result and further steps are same .

Comment: {"error":null,"countries":[{"id":1,"description":"Slovensko","locale":"sk_SK","zipRegexp":"/^\\d{3}\\ ?\\d{2}$/"},{"id":2,"description":"Česká republika","locale":"cs_CZ","zipRegexp":null},{"id":3,"description":"Afganistan","locale":"en_EN","zipRegexp":null},{"id":4,"description":"Albánsko","locale":"en_EN","zipRegexp":null}]}